# Facebook ads - How to create lead generation form using PHP SDK API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have listed the lead generation forms using the below PHP sdk api.

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Page;
$page = new Page(<PAGE_ID>);
$leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms();

print_r($leadgen_forms);
```

I need to create a lead generation form using the PHP sdk API. Is there an api to create the lead form using PHP SDK?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2015/10/09/handling-the-new-lead-ads-form-builder/

Comment: The above url is for Javascript API. Is there any specific API for PHP SDK?